# Inserting elements into a String List

Tags: c#, mongodb

when I use the first code, it perfectly gives words in DB

```
collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(X => Console.WriteLine(X.GetElement("word").Value) );
```

But when I try to get single element by putting all "word"s into a string list, it gives `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error.

```
collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(X => wordStringList.Add(X.GetElement("word").Value.ToString()) );
Console.WriteLine(wordStringList[0]);
```

How can I fix this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely a race-condition, as your `wordStringList.Add` call is going to run *after* your `Console.WriteLine` call due to the use of `ForEachAsync`. You can [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) the `ForEachAsync` and get the expected result, or you can instead use [`Select`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_MongoQueryable_Select__2.htm).

Here's an example of the `Select` approach.

```
var wordStringList = collection.Find(new BsonDocument())
    .Select(X => X.GetElement("word").Value))
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(wordStringList[0]);
```

Of course, this assumes you have at least one value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that because you are using an async method, that it is not done (or even started) by the time you try to write out the first element. So the list is still empty.
You probably need to wait for the async method to complete first, using `await` or `.Wait()` depending on the context

```
await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(X => wordStringList.Add(X.GetElement("word").Value.ToString()) );
Console.WriteLine(wordStringList[0]);
```

or

```
collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(X => wordStringList.Add(X.GetElement("word").Value.ToString())).Wait();
Console.WriteLine(wordStringList[0]);
```

The `await` keyword will only work from within an async method, while `.Wait()` will work in both async and non-async methods.

I'm not not knowledgable enough on the subject to explain the difference between `await` and `.Wait()`, so you'll need to look that up elsewhere, but from what I understand `await` is prefered when available.